# to knock the door of the doctor

Tags: phrase-usage

I was wondering if there is a phrase

> to knock at the door of the doctor

in order to mean "to see a doctor"

or do I get it wrong what the woman says in [this](https://www.4tests.com/examimages/toefl/1_25.mp3) recording.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELL is not a transcription service

Comment: It sounds very odd to me, but I would think it's just one of those unusual British expressions like, *"Knock me up in the morning and we'll go have breakfast together"*.

Comment: Rather than depend on a link that may change or go away in the future, add the relevant text (as you comprehend it) to your question. Then bold the specific part of concern so it is clear what your question is.

Answer (score 3):

The woman says:

> **Had I not gone to the doctor**, I wouldn't have gotten over the flu
>   as quickly.

"Had I not gone to the doctor" is the inverted form of "If I had not gone to the doctor". This is an example of subject/auxiliary inversion and it is usually used in **formal** English.

Here is another example:

> If we had booked our flight earlier, it would have been cheaper.

We omit "if" and move "had" before the subject, so the inverted sentence will be:

> **Had we booked** our flight earlier, it would have been cheaper.

Since your sentence is negative, another thing you should remember is that contracted negative forms are not possible when we use an inverted word order for describing an unreal or impossible situation in the past. so you can't say:

> **Hadn't I gone to the doctor**, I wouldn't have gotten over the flu
>   as quickly.

---

You can use inversion in the first and the second conditionals too.

Here is an example for the first conditional:

> If he remembers his own name, we’ll be able to help him.

To invert this sentence, we replace "if" with "should" and use the simple form of the verb, so the inverted sentence will be:

> **Should he remember** his own name, we’ll be able to help him.

And for the second conditional:

> - **Were it** mine, I wouldn't throw that away. (if it were mine,...)
> - **Did I find** a good job, I would let you know. (If I found a good    job,...)

Comment: You are correct, but to upvote this I would like a more complete explanation of the phrase, and perhaps other examples of how to use it.